# How to trigger youtube vr from oculus's browser?

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus, oculusgo

I have a webpage that embeds VR videos from youtube. However the experience is gruesome in comparison with the youtube VR app itself. Question is: how can I open youtube VR app to play the VR video from a browser's URL? What deep link or custom uri scheme can I use?

I am using oculus go as device and standard oculus vr as browser.

Thank you so much.

tried meta support forum but no success about this question at all even though this is a common question there.